# How to control a process from a different process running in different core

Tags: linux, ipc

I have two processes running in different cores. I want to know what is the fastest way to pause and continue one process from another process.

Answer (score 1):

Well it really depends on the application and the type of communication you are looking for, so I will asume that what you want is indeed a blocking operation.

For that, I will go with Domain Sockets, they have blocking and non blocking operations and are very ease to use, with lot of examples. You can start [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) here in the oficial documentation for Linux.

The concept is the same for any other operating system, only the implementations could differ.

Comment: Well i am using kill command for stopping the process but its taking too much time. I want to stop it within 5 micro seconds but is taking more than 200 micro seconds. Is there any faster way ?

Comment: Hello @ArvindJha, did you edit the initial question? Have you had the answer so far??